# Set custom attribute on button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How can i set custom attributes on an button that is programmatically created?

I have this code to create an button:

```
var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(7 + add), 565, 39, 55))     
            btn.setTitle(String(Array(shuffledWord)[i...i]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
 btn.tag = 7 + add;
```

I can give some value to .tag but are there more thing like that? Can i create custom attributes to set on the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need custom properties on a class that doesn't belong to you, subclass it and use the subclass instead.

```
class MyCoolButton : UIButton {
    var myCoolProperty : String = "coolness"
}
```

And later:

```
var btn = MyCoolButton( // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by looking at the class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/)

What attributes are you directly looking to change about the button?  You can set it's title color, font, border color/width, corner-radius etc.

A lot of these can be mutated by accessing the button's layer as in

`btn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0` and things of that nature.

EDIT: If you are looking to add custom features or store some properties then I would refer to Matt's answer about subclassing.